# return seperate collection referening property of and return also nested collection from same query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm building a nested object (a nested tree of 1 to many... or each node has one to many at each level of depth) from a cypher query whereby I was to return one value which would contain the nested object, and another containing an array of only the IDs in the last nested object object. That is two result columns where one contains the entire tree, and another that contains only the IDs.

Using: Seraph queryRaw(), Neo4j 2.1.3

```
MATCH (oa:ObjectA)-[:has]->(ob:ObjectB)-[:has]->(oc:ObjectC)<-[:extends]-(thing:ObjectThing)
      WHERE ob.year = 2012
      WITH oa, ob, oc, collect(thing.uuid) as uuids
      WITH uuids, oa, ob, collect({name:oc.name, uuid:oc.uuid, reference:thing.uuid}) AS objectCs
      WITH uuids, oa, collect({name:ob.name, year:ab.year, objectCs:objectCs}) AS objectBs
      RETURN {name:oa.name, country:oa.country, objectCs:objectCs} AS objectAs, uuids as documents
```

However it appears that it breaks the results into multiple repeating values, while if I remove the initial collect, the tree is properly built. e.g.

```
columns: [ 'objectAs', 'documents']
data: 
[
  [ 
    { 
      name:'oa name', 
      country: 'oa country',
      objectBs: 
        [    // one to many
          {
            name: 'ob name',
            year: 2013...
             ... array of one to many oc nested objects ...}
          }
        ]
    },
    [ '0000494949499' ]
  ],
  [
    { 
      name:'oa other name', 
      country: 'oa other country',
      objectBs: [{ ... one to many nested objects like above...}]
    },
    [ '1234124331243' ]
  ]
]

MATCH (oa:ObjectA)-[:has]->(ob:ObjectB)-[:has]->(oc:ObjectC)<-[:extends]-(thing:ObjectThing)
      WHERE ob.year = 2012
      WITH oa, ob, collect({name:oc.name, uuid:oc.uuid, reference:thing.uuid}) AS objectCs
      WITH oa, collect({name:ob.name, year:ab.year, objectCs:objectCs}) AS objectBs
      RETURN {name:oa.name, country:oa.country, objectCs:objectCs} AS objectAs

columns: [ 'objectAs']
data: 
[
  [ 
    { 
      name:'oa name', 
      country: 'oa country',
      objectBs: [{ ... nested objects ...}]
    },
    { 
      name:'oa other name', 
      country: 'oa other country',
      objectBs: [{ ... nested objects ...}]
    }
  ]
]
```

I am trying to get the following:

```
columns: [ 'objectAs', 'documents']
data: 
[
  [     // index 0 would represent column 'objectAs'
    { 
      name:'oa name', 
      country: 'oa country',
      objectBs: [{ ... nested objects ...}]
    },
    { 
      name:'oa other name', 
      country: 'oa other country',
      objectBs: [{ ... nested objects ...}]
    }
  ]
  [    // index 1 would represent column 'documents'
    '0000494949499', 
    '1234124331243' 
  ]

]
```

**In short: I simply want to build a nested result of all the one to many down the 4 levels BUT have a separate result column of all the UUIDs found in the last (thing) node, that is I do not wish to iterate over the cypher results to collect them all.**

Comment: Which objects are connected one-to-many? And for which object type are you trying to collect `:ObjectThing`s. From the output of the first query, I'm guessing that `:ObjectC` is related 1-to-1 with `:ObjectThing`, and that's why it returns 1-item arrays of documents

Comment: Yes, sorry, its a 1 to many for all from the left edge to right, so a (1 to many) to b, b (1 to many) b... I'll update the question, good point thanks.

Comment: Let me know if my edits convey the point of (a) 1 to many of (b), each (b) one to many of (c), each (c) one to many of (thing).

Comment: It still confuses me that you have c.reference = thing.uuid, which suggests that it's a *-to-1 relation from :ObjectC to :ObjectThing (otherwise it should be c.references = collect(thing.uuid)). If this is the case, please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to aggregate the uuids too:

i.e. something like:

```
  MATCH (oa:ObjectA)-[:has]->(ob:ObjectB)-[:has]->(oc:ObjectC)<-[:extends]-(thing:ObjectThing)
  WHERE ob.year = 2012
  WITH oa, ob, oc, collect(thing.uuid) as uuids
  WITH collect(uuids) as uuids, oa, ob, collect({name:oc.name, uuid:oc.uuid, reference:thing.uuid}) AS objectCs
  WITH collect(uuids) as uuids, oa, collect({name:ob.name, year:ab.year, objectCs:objectCs}) AS objectBs
  RETURN {name:oa.name, country:oa.country, objectCs:objectCs} AS objectAs, uuids as documents
```

if you don't want to have the nested collections of uuids you can do

```
  reduce(a=[]; x in collect(uuids) | a + x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the `thing` ids and `ObjectC`s in the same `WITH` clause:

```
MATCH (oa:ObjectA)-[:has]->(ob:ObjectB {year: 2012})-[:has]->(oc:ObjectC)<-[:extends]-(thing:ObjectThing)
    WITH oa, ob, collect({name:oc.name, uuid:oc.uuid, reference:thing.uuid}) AS objectCs, collect(thing.uuid) as uuids
    WITH uuids, oa, collect({name:ob.name, year:ab.year, objectCs:objectCs}) AS objectBs
    RETURN {name:oa.name, country:oa.country, objectCs:objectCs} AS objectAs, uuids as documents
```